# How to determine the input type of a web element using Selenium Webdriver + Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to determine the type of web element? I want to determine whether a web element is a textbox or a dropdown box. Is there a way to determine that using webdriver + Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getTagName()` and `getAttribute(java.lang.String name)` methods defined in `WebElement` interface (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Comment: link is currently dead. try: [seleniumhq.github.io](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)